# Serializing a class in the class boost

Tags: c++, class, boost-serialization

I try to serialize a class `MFace` with the help of BOOST,

```
// class of the face
class MFace
{
     public:
         //constructor
         MFace();
     private:

    //! Vector of the face nodes
        mymath::Vector<DG::MNode*> Nodes;

        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
            void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
                //! Vector of the face nodes
                ar & Nodes;
            }
 };
```

but the class contains another class

```
mymath::Vector<MNode*> Nodes;
```

so, when I try to write `Nodes` into archive

```
//create a face
MFace Face;

//archive output file
std::ofstream ofs("output.txt");
boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);
// Write data to archive
ar & Face;
    ...
```

the compiler gives me an error

```
error: ‘class mymath::Vector<DG::MNode*>’ has no member named ‘serialize’
```

Should I add another 'serialize' to each class that MFace uses (particulary mymath::Vector, and MNodes) and describe what it shoud do, or is it somehow possible to resolve it within MFace not touching other classes?

The includes are

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
//contains mymath::Vector<>
#include "mymath/vector.h"

//containes MNodes
#include "MNode.h"
#include <fstream>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is if I am remembering my boost serialization correctly...

You COULD add to the serialize method inside of MFace, like this:

```
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
//of the face nodes
    for( <loop to travel through each node in the Nodes vector> )
    {
        ar & currentNode.var1;
        ar & currentNode.var2;
        ar & currentNode.var3;
    }
}
```

This is assuming that each of the members inside of of the Node object is a type that the boost library can serialize.

The problem with this, however, is that you completely couple the MFace class to the MNode type - that is, if you add a member to MNode, you then have to remember to add it to the serialization of the MFace class.

Further, if you add any sort of complex object to the MFace class that boost does not know how to serialize, you then have to serialize that member by member.

It is better for serialization for each object to know how to serialize itself - the definition of how to serialize should be contained in the serialize() method for each class.

If you add the serialize method to the DG::MNode class, this problem should go away.

Comment: So, decomposition of MNodes within MFace actually worked. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: No problem - just remember that when you use the decomposition, it will make your life much harder in the long run, if there is any chance of MNodes changing, or MFace changing significantly as well.